# Spreading 45 characters (36 letters and 9 digits) into multiple rows using CSS

Tags: html, css

Everyone. I have an unordered list of 45 characters (36 Devanagari letters and 9 digits). I am struggling to align them to multiple rows using CSS. I want to spread the letters into 4 rows of 12, 9, 9 and 6 letters respectively and the 9 digits into another row. How can I go about doing it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you include your current attempt at completing your code. What have you tried so far? What have you done to solve the issue yourself? By showing you have been willing to try, and you'll more likely get a more willing community to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `display:inline;`

```css
.row li{
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<ol class="row">
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
</ol>
<ol class="row">
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
</ol>
<ol class="row">
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
</ol>
<ol class="row">
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
<li>a</li>
</ol>
</ul>
```

Comment: A quick question, though. I am trying to give absolute positions to the rows to arrange them. However, the fourth and fifth row doesn't seem to stack up properly. Is there anything I am doing wrong? Here is what I have done so far. http://jsfiddle.net/2dj6qtfh/1/

Comment: Your code is correct but you missed to close the `ul` tag for `row3`. You closed that tag after `row5`.

Comment: and instead of `row1` `row2` and so on, you can use `.alphabet:nth-child()` doc link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Looks like I made it to work. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: No problem. :) :)